# Facebook AR Studio - Importing Animations

Tags: facebook, 3d, augmented-reality

I'm trying to import a 3d object in .fbx format into the Facebook AR Studio. The object was created and animated in Blender. The AR Studio does not support 'Baked' animations, but I'm wondering if it's possible to somehow import the animation into the studio, as opposed to scripting the entire animation, due to the complexity of the object (number of bones and motions).

I'm new to AR and 3d modeling so any input or direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This should be possible now, as of AR Studio version 38. After you import your FBX file into ARS you will see in the Assets panel that the animation is included. Add the object to your scene. By default it will not animate!

To enable the animation, select the object in your scene - in the inspector panel on the right, you will see an Animation section. Click on the + symbol to the right of where it says "Animation" and select the imported animation. This will import the animation into the Patch Editor. From there, you can control the animation. It is possible to also trigger the animation via script, but to do that you would need to create a script to Patch Editor "bridge." Hope this helps!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi, I imported the animations and the object. When I go to 'Animation' property, it's grayed out with a message 'No controller selected', how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem to be possible at the moment. If you read this interview from Tetsuro Mise at the Mill, there's a passage hinting at the fact that it's not implemented at the moment and to do so, they had to create a workaround with their engineers and people at Facebook:

> The process to ensure its realistic movement in the Facebook camera
>   effects platform wasn't straight forward at all! Animation data needs
>   translating from MAYA to Blender to the AR studio, where Facebook
>   authorizes camera effects. Our 3D teams and engineers, as well as the
>   Facebook tech team, spent great amount of time to establish this
>   seamless integration. After countless failure and debugs, we finally
>   success to obtain a smooth work flow.

http://www.themill.com/millchannel/1551/a-look-at-facebook-ar-effects-with-the-mill-ny-s-tetsuro-mise

If someone has a good answer for this, please, share it !